# Unsupervised analysis of sparse binary variables

Tags: clustering, binary-data

I have a dataset with approx 5,000 customers (ID). Each customer bought between 1 and 20 different items (I) (total of 10,000 different items) ordered within classes of items (C) (total of 450). All items and classes are coded as binary variables. Now, I´d like to identify if there are clusters of C´s and I´s but I assume the nested structure within each ID must be taken care of, and also I dont know how well the unsupervised learning techniques can be used with binary data.

My plan is to create two heatmaps, the first with each ID on the y-axis and the C´s on the x-axis. I could then subsequently do the same with C´s along the y-axis and I´s along the X-axis. For both I could do hierarchical clustering using Manhattan distance to see which items and classes are clustered.

Does that seem like a fair procedure or is there any other preferred methods?

Comment: creating a heatmap between IDs and Cs is straightforward, no statistical method required. the problem is how to read a 5000x450 variables heatmap without loosing your mind.

Comment: I'm not sure what putting the customer IDs on y-axis gives you. In general, though, clustering techniques will work with binary data. But your main concern should be the total number of features in your data set. I'd consider administering some form of dimensionality reduction techniques (e.g. MCA) to reduce the number of features your clustering technique uses.